# How can I implement click to zoom functionality in Bixby?

Tags: bixby

Bixby staff recommended that I implement click to zoom functionality for viewing text images in my capsule. How could i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I did some digging and I think the best way to implement this would be making the image lightbox enabled.

this would look something like

```
image {
  lightbox-enabled (true)
  aspect-ratio (4:3)
  url (https://test/image.png)
}
```

Some more information can be found about it in the docs [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout.content.section.content.image.lightbox-enabled). A warning though, this works on device but does not yet work in the simulator.
Other things that might be helpful would be [object-fit](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout.content.section.content.image-list.object-fit) or [aspect-ratio](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout.content.section.content.image.aspect-ratio).